# Where are "My Selling Tools", "Website preferences", and "Instant payment notifications" in new Paypal website?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm pretty confused with new PayPal. I have sandbox accounts, but now I needed to create production (business) account for actual real payment. But all look and feel are different now and all the links are different. Seems Paypal changed their web. I've already done integration for previous client; but now I'm disappointed because I can't figure out where to set various parameters. When I log in, nowhere I can found "My Selling Tools".

Where can I found what was available until now:

Paypal -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Website preferences

Paypal -> Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Instant payment notifications

?

I need to enter Website preferences in order to set needed params, and also I need to set some parameters in Instant payment notifications. Please help me. I need this kind of settings to enter:

https://docs.shopify.com/support/settings/checkout-and-payment/do-my-customers-need-a-paypal-account-to-pay-with-paypal

Comment: I sympathise entirely, but the question is off-topic.

Comment: Where can i ask it then on stackowerflow?

Comment: You can't. Ask at Paypal support.

Answer (score 9):

If your PayPal layout page had been changed into new style, please do the following steps.

**Website Payment Preferences:**

Login PayPal -> Header Icon(Business Profile) -> Profile and settings -> My selling tools -> Website preferences -> Update

Or

after log in PayPal.com , directly link below URL.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments

**Instant Payment Notification (IPN):**

Login PayPal -> Header Icon(Business Profile) -> Profile and settings -> My selling tools -> Instant payment notifications -> Update

Or

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify

Comment: This option is only available if you have Business PayPal account.

Comment: My selling tools is no where to be found. The direct links you provided do work however.

Answer (score 2):

From the new PayPal dashboard, scroll down a little bit to the middle of the page, on the left hand side, there's **Seller Preferences** under **Selling Tools**. Click on it. You will have access to the place where you can setup PDT, IPN, and API keys, etc.

Shortcut to that page: 
[PayPal Seller Preferences](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-display-handler&tab_id=SELLER_PREFERENCES)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to updating the Website Payment preferences.

1. Log into https://sandbox.paypal.com
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Website payments under PRODUCTS & SERVICES. And you will find both "Website preferences”, and “Instant payment notifications” options
4. Click update Next to options

(see the attached image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayzqf.png)

Answer (score 1):

Steps: Settings->Account Settings->Website Payments->Website Preferences
URL: https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/preferences/website

Then enable Auto return with the success URL

Answer (score 0):

**Website Payment Preferences:**

Top right menu:
"Your Name" popup menu ->
Account settings

Then on the left menu there is the entry "Website Payments" on the bottom of the left menu. This entry might be invisible. Then you must make the view on the screen smaller by pressing Ctrl-minus ("-" button) on Firefox. Then the right side will have the entry **Website preferences**.

After clicking on it you get a new screen where you set "Auto return for website payments" or "Auto return" to on. Then you also activate "Payment data transfer". Then a text and key "Identity Token: xxxxxxxx" will show up for a moment. It will vanish automatically if you leave this page. Redo the last step again (uncheck and check) to see it again.

**Instant Payment Notification (IPN):**

Do the same as above for "Website Payment Preferences" until you have clicked on "Website preferences".
On the right list you will have an entry "Instant payment notifications".
Then a new page will appear with the possibility to activate it.
"Instant Payment Notification (IPN)"